# PHP App Server Integrated to Web

Tags: php, sockets, httprequest

I want to build a php server that will record my desktop apps activity and display it on my website.

So, my desktop app will send json data about client activity to the php server (like last login use app, is active now / not, app data) and display it on my web.

Something like this (i will have multiple client connected)

[image: Sample UI]

My question is, how to do that (server side) using serversocket or request (get / post)

thanks anyway.

Comment: Makes absolutely no difference either way, really.

Comment: yeah, but where to place server.php?
i use laravel framework for my web,

Comment: i must hold all current client data to database or just an array?

Comment: Place it wherever you want... configure your server appropriately to read from wherever you put it.  And, if you want persistent data, you need to write it out somewhere, such as a database.